# Anyone aware of an open source EPCIS python application or module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, open-source, barcode, rfid

Can't seem to find any python or recent (1.2) open source EPCIS platforms anywhere.  Looking to do a quick RFID/barcoding project and need GS1 EPCIS 1.2 components or anything that could help build such components.

Comment: Take a look at EPCPyYes: https://pypi.org/project/EPCPyYes/

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Thanks chris.  I'm looking to parse and store the data in an EPCIS 1.2 XML document into a database or something i can use to create reports from.  I'd rather not write than in scratch and would like to stick to python.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, I know of a fantastic Open Source EPCIS System called Quartet. I am implementing it right now. You can find it here :

https://gitlab.com/serial-lab/qu4rtet

This system is built by people who have been writing L4/L3 systems for Track, Trace, and Serialization for years and years. It's actually better than Systech, TraceLink, Antares, Adents, rfXcel, Verify Brand/Optel and any other commercial system I have ever used.